When using an array of dummy variables in regression analysis, do I need to drop one of the dummies if there are missing values in the data?
I'm running a fixed effects regression with my dependent variable as life satisfaction score and main independent variable as education level. The education variables are broken down into the following categories:

Degree
Other higher degree
A Level etc.
GCSE etc.
Other qualification
No qualification
Inapplicable
No response

I am only including dummy variables for degree down to no qualification, with the assumption the those with inapplicable or no response answers are captured in the constant/intercept. Am I correct in thinking that this means that I will not fall into the dummy variable trap?

If by "dummy variable trap" you mean perfect collinearity of the dummies, then it would depend on the values / counts in the inapplicable or no response categories. If those two dummies are all zeros, then there's still a problem. However, I'm guessing that that's not what you meant or have in your data, so it would work. Still, it might make more sense to use the "no qualification" category as the baseline (i.e., to drop it), since it's probably easier to interpret the results of the other education levels.
